# Tensorflow show model summary

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a UNet that I trained and saved the model. I want to see the model summary but when I use `model.summary()` the `Output Shape` column is cut off and cant see the full shape. The model was trained on 3D images so the output should show `(None, shapeX, shapeY, shapeZ, num_features)`. How can I show the full Output Shape?

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
        
model = load_model('model.h5',compile = False)
model.summary()
```

model.summary()

[image: model]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can set the `line_length` property of the `tf.summary` function.

```
model.summary(line_length = 100)
```